# Python popen to read data from process, but with drops in stdout

Tags: python, process, stdout, popen

I am using a generator `getBytes` to retrieve bytes from a process STDOUT (STDOUT is being output at a rate of about 5MB/s)

The issue is that when my program spends time processing this (a few seconds), parts of STDOUT seem to have been dropped.
I have tried setting bufsize to a large value (100000000) in the subprocess.Popen call, but that does not seem to solve the issue.

```
def getBytes():
    # command = "command that outputs data"
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    for c in iter(lambda: process.stdout.read(1), b''):
        yield(c)

mybytes = getBytes()
buffer = []
for b in mybytes:
    buffer.append(b)
    if len(buffer)>=MIN_BUFFER:
        # some processing that may take a few seconds
        # after that, drops in STDOUT
        buffer = []
```

Comment: Do you have any visibility into the subprocess' workings? Might it be dropping output if a write would block (as could happen if your program is busy processing data so the pipe fills up)?

Comment: If I pipe the subprocess to a file then I get all the data without any drops, so the subprocess in itself seems to output data just fine

Comment: A file won't fill up and block like a pipe will, so that's not a representative test for what I suspect the problem is. I believe piping to `less` and not scrolling the output could present a similar situation however.